# MAIL NOT SHOWING UP

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$to      = 'something@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: example@test.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: example@test.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);



$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers );
if ($send)
$mailReturns = "Mail sent successfully.";
else
$mailReturns = "Mail sent failed.";

?>
<?php echo $mailReturns; ?>
```

after run it shows mail sent successfully
but mail not showing up in any of the accounts. iv tried gmail, yahoo, rediff and ibibo why????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have qmail installed on your server, try using that.  Alternatively, there is a nice PHP mailer class called swiftmail that is available here: http://swiftmailer.org/ you can try.

Your emails are probably being junked/marked as spam.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see in spam folder.